# How does js files behave when same lwc is repeated in a component?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, code

I'm working on an lwc where I noticed an interesting behavior.

Scenario:
I have an lwc with the name "myLwc"(imaginary). It has the following files.

- myLwc.html
- myLwc.js
- myLwc.js-meta.xml
- state.js (A helper js file to add some methods)

the content of state.js is as below (this is also imaginary, but this represents the scenario well)

```
//start
let counter = 0;

export function increment(){
    counter = counter + 1;
    console.log(counter);
}
//end
```

Now, I'm adding the same LWC multiple times in the same component. Similar to below

```
<c-my-lwc></c-my-lwc>
<c-my-lwc></c-my-lwc>
<c-my-lwc></c-my-lwc>
<c-my-lwc></c-my-lwc>
```

I'm calling the helper method in the connected callback of myLwc.js as shown below (Note, all the import statements are added, I'm only showing the code which actually invokes the method).

```
connectedCallback(){
    increment();
}
```

I was expecting each LWC to have its own counter. So the output would ideally look like

```
1
1
1
1
```

However, the actual output was

```
1
2
3
4
```

Seems like all 4 instances of the LWC shared the same variable. What sort of behavior is this? Is this expected? Is it a good idea to leverage this behavior to build LWC features? Is there any documentation of this behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What sort of behavior is this? Is this expected?

These are a type of "static" variables, formally called "module-scoped variables". A static variable is one that is defined, and stored, in exactly one place, and all code that references the variable can equally access it. You can think of such a variable belonging to the file ("module") in which it was declared, rather than part of the class that is accessing it. This is also true for any variables you define outside of a class within your component. Here's an [example](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/0TbU7UARj6BNTqloPE5c/src/counterDisplay.js?p=stories) that demonstrates this behavior.

> Is this expected?

This is well expected for veteran programmers. This behavior has been around since the beginning of JavaScript, and is present in many older languages dating back to at least the 1970s (I'm not old enough to know much beyond K&R's C).

Just remember that a variable defined inside a class or object is an "instance" variable, and outside any object or class are "static" (also called "global") variables. Note that if you don't export the symbol for the variable, it is only accessible inside that file/module.

> Is it a good idea to leverage this behavior to build LWC features?

It can be. For example, [pubpub](https://github.com/developerforce/pubsub) uses this behavior to allow components to communicate across the DOM regardless of location. There are better ways of achieving this specific task in Salesforce LWC ([Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation)), but the point is that if you need shared access to data or functions, this is the way to do it. For example, pubsub might be useful in a LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) environment to coordinate component data/events.

You can use this technique to reduce memory usage by storing large objects in a single location, to coordinate activities across components, store a common configuration object, and so on.

> Is there any documentation to this behavior?

Yes, you can read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) or ES6 specification. There are three types of "variable scope". The MDN says this:

> The scope is the current context of execution in which values and expressions are "visible" or can be referenced. If a variable or expression is not in the current scope, it will not be available for use. Scopes can also be layered in a hierarchy, so that child scopes have access to parent scopes, but not vice versa.
>
> JavaScript has the following kinds of scopes:
>
> - Global scope: The default scope for all code running in script mode.
> - Module scope: The scope for code running in module mode.
> - Function scope: The scope created with a function.

Global variables do not exist in Salesforce LWC. Everything is either a module- or function-scoped variable. This is because LS (Locker Service) and Lightning LWS (Lightning Web Security) provide a faux global object for each namespace, to prevent leaking data across namespaces accidentally. However, global scope does exist in LWR, which is the [open-source version](https://lwc.dev/) that you can run outside of Salesforce. Anything you declare outside of a function, object, or class is a module-scoped variable. Only one instance of that variable exists.

It is important to note that such variables do not trigger reactivity, so do not use them if you need them to be reactive. For example:

```
let display = false;
export default class MyComponent extends LightningElement {
  get display() {
    return display;
  }
  handleToggleClick() {
    display = !display;
  }
}
```

When a button is clicked to toggle the flag, the LWC [may](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/jp8GXK44uMxW0K3ZBRXL/src/app.css?p=stories) or [may not](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/Xs3HmMQcuzMUR1Jkak4V/src/app.css?p=stories) refresh, depending on if anything *else* triggers reactivity. You should be aware of this limitation to avoid any unpleasant surprises.

---

This is a feature of many, many languages, so you'll always need to be aware of that nuance if you go programming in most languages. Anything you put in an "object" is its own unique copy, and anything you put in a "static" or "global" scope will exist across some, or all, code that uses it. For example, in Apex, a static variable is used across an entire transaction (but not *all* transactions at once), while in some web server technology, such variables are exposed to every transaction that uses that variable.

Comment: Such an insightful answer, thanks

Answer (score 4):

The behavior of the helper file is as it is expected. As you need to hold different states for each component in the iteration you can do something like this in the `helper.js`.

```
export default class MyCounter {
    constructor() {
        this.counter = 0;
    }
  
    increment(){
        this.counter = this.counter + 1;
        console.log(this.counter);
    }
}
```

Then import the class and initialize the object the connected callback.

```
connectedCallback(){
    this.counter = new MyCounter();
    this.counter.increment();
}
```